# Primitive of the function $(\sin x)/x$

Tags: integration, functions, special-functions

I know that for some functions, for instance $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$, there does not exist a primitive.

Does there is a primitive for the function $f(x) = \frac{\operatorname{sin}(x)}{x}$?

Comment: Technically, there exists a primitive, it just isn't representable in terms of the standard elementary functions.

Comment: Did you mean $\sec(x)$?

Comment: Sorry, it's $sen(x) = sin(x)$.

Comment: Although there is no primitive in tesm of standard functions, as Thomas indicated, but that does not mean that integrals couldn't be evaluated. When integrating from 0 to infinity, answers are known!

Comment: See [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).

Answer (score 2):

No It is not In terms of elementary functions, But we can write in Infinite Series form.

Using $$\displaystyle \sin x= x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+..........$$

So $$\displaystyle \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}.........$$

So $$\displaystyle \int \frac{\sin x}{x}dx = \int \left\{1-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}.........\right\}dx$$